# 1d coupled field PDE in MMA

Tags: differential-equations

how can we correctly solve 1d coupled field pde in MMA 12?

***Description for the problem***: the article [the phase field fracture model in one dimension](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/pamm.201210071)

I have proposed the following code (based on the solution from @Alex Trounev and @Cesareo), and found that:

**Numerical solution from MMA**

[image: numerical]

**Correct solution needs to look like**:

[image: Solution_Phase-field]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
PDE1 = (s[t, x])^2 D[u[t, x], x, x] == D[u[t, x], t];
PDE2 = 2 \[Epsilon] D[s[t, x], x, x] + 0.5 (1 - s[t, x])/\[Epsilon] - 
    s[t, x] (D[u[t, x], x])^2 == D[s[t, x], t];

lr = 25;
ll = -25;
u0 = 10;
\[Epsilon] = 0.125;
bcs1 = {u[t, ll] == -t u0 , u[t, lr] == t u0 };
bcs2 = {s[t, ll] == 1, s[t, lr] == 1};
bcs3 = {Derivative[0, 1][s][t, ll] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][s][t, lr] == 0};
ic = {u[0, x] == t u0 x/lr, s[0, x] == 1};
sols = NDSolve[{PDE1, PDE2, bcs1, bcs2, ic}, {u, s}, {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}]
utx = Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sols]
stx = Evaluate[s[t, x] /. sols]
Show[Plot3D[stx, {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], PlotRange -> All]
```

PDE Model:

> Coupled Eqs.:
>
> $0=s^{2} u^{\prime\prime}$
>
> $0=s  (u^{\prime})^{2}-\left(2 \epsilon s^{\prime \prime}+\frac{1-s}{2
> \epsilon}\right)$
>
> BCs:
>
> $u(x=\pm L)=\pm u_{0} t$
>
> $s^{\prime}( \pm L)=0$
>
> and
>
> Initial Value for s(x)=1;
>
> $s \in[0,1]$;

Comment: Is that the equation you really want to solve?

Comment: @Xminer  sure, see the updated infos for more details!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the initial conditions

```
ic = {u[0, x] == t u0 x/lr, s[0, x] == 1};
```

there is an inconsistency because it is taken at $t = 0$.

Making

```
ic = {u[0, x] == 0, s[0, x] == 1};
```

it works fine.

```
sols = NDSolve[{PDE1, PDE2, bcs1, bcs2, ic}, {u, s}, {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}]
utx = Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sols]
stx = Evaluate[s[t, x] /. sols]
Show[Plot3D[utx, {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All],
Plot3D[stx, {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: I have changed the code, but it does not solve correctly, e.g.{Plot3D[uu1[t, x], {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[vv1[t, x], {x, ll, lr}, {t, 0, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]}

Comment: @ABCDEMMM I included some additional commands to visualize the results. I used  **NDSolve** instead **NDSolveValue**

Comment: thanks you! but the solution from MMA is not correct, I have updated more details about this issue, see update infos!